# Creating a new class more than once

Tags: javascript

I have various javascript classes.

A class is created like so:

```
this.user = new app.User();
```

My question is, if I were to call the above again and again and again (every time I open a modal) would there be any memory issues? Would the old class just be replaced by a new copy as I am assigning it to the same user var? Anything I need to consider?

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to create an empty list with the type of that class and then every time you create a new instance from that class initialize the last index undefined object :)

this will manage your classes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you var is already an object of the class, if no - create it.

```
this.user = (this.user instanceof app.User) ? this.user : new app.User();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll need a new instance for each modal load.